# limit of characters in html

Tags: asp.net, html

I have set the limit of characters on textbox but while typing the input if it exceeds from 9 character it continues type it another field without use of tab

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-regex="Please enter valid SSN" data-val-regex-pattern="^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$" id="Ssn" name="Ssn" type="text" value="" class="valid">
```

I want it should stop to take input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use jQuery for example

```
<input data-val="true" maxlength=9 data-val-regex="Please enter valid SSN" data-val-regex-pattern="^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$" id="Ssn" name="Ssn" type="text" value="" class="valid"><br>
<script lang="text/javascript">
    $("#Ssn").keyup(function(e)
    {
        var str=$("#Ssn").val();
        if(str.length==9)
        {
            $("#Ssn").blur();
        }
    });
</script>
```

at this code you must include jQuery before

** Edit Misunderstanding

Comment: The OP did NOT want the text to continue into the next field, that was an unwanted effect that he wanted to stop.

Comment: Maybe change t keyup event to be keypress. That way you can just blur and return false if t lenght is already 9

Answer (score 0):

Use the maxlength attribute

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-regex="Please enter valid SSN" data-val-regex-pattern="^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$" id="Ssn" name="Ssn" type="text" value="" class="valid" maxlength="9">
```

Comment: It should stop any input past 9 characters...not sure why this is not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

pattern attribute regular expressions aren't fully supported in all browsers--specifically, those that do support them don't always obey complex regular expressions. I've noticed this in Safari, at least.

The `maxlength` attribute SHOULD work. Not sure why it's not for you. Maybe post a JSBIN example for us to look at.

That said, for complex client-side form validation, you still need to rely on javascript to support a broader range of browsers.